# How to Pass a std::string variable into a function

Tags: c++, stdstring

I have a C++ method that takes one variable the method signature is like this:

```cpp
DLL returnObject** getObject( const std::string folder = "" );
```

I tried passing in:

```cpp
const std::string myString = "something";
```

but I get the following error:

```cpp
No matching function call to ... getObject( std::string&);
```

I have a couple questions here.

1. How do I pass in a normal `std::string` without the `&`
2. This looks like the value is optional `folder = ""` is it? And if so how do you pass an optional parameter?

Comment: Can you please show us exactly how you tried to call the `getObject` function with the parameter? I'm betting your issue is there.

Comment: Hi i tried this   const std::string folder = "";
  className->getObject( folder );

Comment: Perhaps `extern "C"` would help?

Comment: -1 "DLL returnObject**"? Doesn't look like normal (iPhone) C++ to me...

Comment: Untagging `iphone` and `objective-c` because there is nothing at all in this question relating to either of those.

Comment: This cannot be the right code. For one, I somewhat doubt anyone who doesn't know to pass strings by reference would bother about adding `const` (although it is possible). What's more, your error message is referring to a function taking the string by non-`const` reference - which is a completely different one. So post the real code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This little example works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

class foo {
public:
    void getObject( const std::string folder = "" );
};

int main ()
{
    const std::string myString = "something";

    foo* pFoo = new foo;

    pFoo->getObject( myString);
    pFoo->getObject();    // call using default parameter

    return 0;
}


void foo::getObject( const std::string folder)
{
    printf( "folder is: \"%s\"\n", folder.c_str());
}
```

You might want to post a similarly small example that shows your problem.

Comment: Thanks i was being stupid the method actually had multiple variables and i was just assuming that it was the std::string that was the cause of the issue.

Comment: Oh man, the last time I used C-style IO in a C++ answer I got snapped at (or was it a question... I can't remember). +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This compiled fine for me, compare it to what you're doing:

```
#include <string>

void myFunc(const std::string _str)
{
}

int main()
{
    const std::string str = "hello world";
    myFunc(str);
    return 0;
}
```